# Select all rows where dates are within a two hour span

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table:

| id | phoneNo | transactionDateTime | transactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:46:51:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 3 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:52:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 4 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 12:53:00:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 5 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 6 | 234567 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 7 | 546345 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 8 | 874655 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |

I need to get all the entries where more than 4 transactions have happened for the same `phoneNo`and the `transactionDateTime`'s are within a 2 hour span, so in the case above, id 1 to 5 have the same phoneNo and are within the 2 hour span, so the result would be

| id | phoneNo | transactionDateTime | transactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:46:51:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 3 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:52:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 4 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 12:53:00:00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 5 | 123456 | 2022-03-15 11:49:52:00 | 2022-03-15 |

So far, I have been able to query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM txnTable
WHERE phoneNo IN
  (SELECT phoneNo 
   FROM txnTable 
   GROUP BY phoneNo, transactionDate
   HAVING COUNT(phoneNo) > 4 )
```

which only groups all entries by date and not the 2 hour timespan. Would appreciate any help on how to write a query in this particular scenario.

Comment: ' within a 2 hour span' - of what? Very first call and recurring chunks of every 2 hours until >= last call?

Comment: within 2 hour span of each other, for example, if 5 different transactions are within a 2-hour gap of each other

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that means there is a chance that every call could overlap over multiple 2 hour spans and you would be interested in all calls 2 hours relative to each call (ie + or - 2  hours) - could get messy? Also is a situation where id 5 has an earlier time than id 4 normal?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server `floor` function to group your `transactionDateTime` every 2 hours.

```
SELECT * FROM txnTable
WHERE phoneNo IN
  (SELECT phoneNo 
   FROM txnTable 
   GROUP BY phoneNo,  transactionDate, floor(datepart(hh, transactionDateTime)/2
   HAVING COUNT(phoneNo) > 4  and floor(datepart(hh, transactionDateTime)/2) = 2)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks @Ed. But unfortunately the problem with this query is it grabs all phone numbers even the ones that are not within the 2 hour range.

Comment: @ArpanKc, add it to the filter, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Choose every row from the table, as long as the number of records with the same phoneno and within 2 hours each way is 4

```
SELECT * 
FROM txnTable t1
WHERE 
    4= (SELECT count(*)
        FROM txnTable t2
        WHERE t2.phoneNo=t1.phoneNo
          AND abs(datediff(second, 
                           t1.transactionDateTime, 
                           t2.transactionDateTime
                           )
                  ) <=2*3600
       )
ORDER BY phoneNo, transactionDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the hour difference between 2 rows which is inside a partitioned bucket and arrive at the max of differences within that bucket. Once that is deduced, it can be filtered using the "2 hours" criteria as below.

```
declare @tbl table(id int identity(1,1)
,phoneNo int,transactionDateTime datetime,transactionDate date
)

insert into @tbl(phoneNo,transactionDateTime,transactionDate)
values
('123456','2022-03-15 11:46:51:00','2022-03-15')
,('123456','2022-03-15 11:49:52:00','2022-03-15')
,('123456','2022-03-15 11:52:52:00','2022-03-15')
,('123456','2022-03-15 12:53:00:00','2022-03-15')
,('123456','2022-03-15 11:49:52:00','2022-03-15')
,('234567','2022-03-15 11:49:52:00','2022-03-15')
,('546345','2022-03-15 11:49:52:00','2022-03-15')
,('874655','2022-03-15 11:49:52:00','2022-03-15')

select id,phoneNo,transactionDateTime,transactionDate 
from(
select *,max(hourdiff)over(partition by phoneNo order by transactionDateTime
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
) as [maxhours] from(
select *
,DATEDIFF(hour, transactionDateTime , max(transactionDateTime)over(partition by phoneNo 
order by transactionDateTime rows between current row and 1 following 
)) AS hourdiff
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by phoneNo order by phoneNo) rownum
,count(1)over(partition by phoneNo order by phoneNo) [count]
from 
@tbl
)t)t
where t.[count] > 4 and 
t.maxhours <= 2  
and t.maxhours <>0
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something:

```
SELECT PHONENO, COUNT(*)-2 AS HOWMANY FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT T1.PHONENO, TRUNC(ABS((TO_DATE(T2.TransactionDateTime, 'MM-DD- 
      YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -TO_DATE(T1.TransactionDateTime, 'MM-DD-YYYY 
      HH24:MI:SS'))*24*60)) 
AS MINUTES_BETWEEN 
FROM YOURTABLE  T1 JOIN YOURTABLE T2 ON T1.PHONENO=T2.PHONENO 
)
WHERE  MINUTES_BETWEEN <120
GROUP BY PHONENO
HAVING COUNT(*) >=4
```

I hope it helps.
Problem is in Oracle and all that with to_date and that format is because i have an alter session with a specific date format.

Comment: Also this-  WITH t1 AS (
SELECT phoneno, transactiondate,
lead(transactiondatetime,4) OVER(PARTITION BY phoneno ORDER BY transactiondatetime) date_5
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM yourtable ) b
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.phoneno FROM t1
INNER JOIN yourtable a
ON t1.phoneno = a.phoneno
WHERE ((TO_DATE(date_5, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -TO_DATE(TransactionDateTime, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))*24*60)< 120
ORDER BY 1;